# Mouse pointer over dygraph not working properly

Tags: dygraphs

I have rotated the dygrpah by 90deg. But now when I mouseover the graph , the mouse pointer gets out of sync and does not point to actual point in graph.

added below  code to get mouse co-ordinates in graph

> var canvasx = Math.abs(canvasCoords[0] - area.h - area.x * 1.5);
>
> var canvasy = Math.abs(canvasCoords[1] - area.h - area.x * 1.5);

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: While there's not enough information in your question to really know what's going on, you may find this discussion helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dygraphs-users/pXrjG8fSxKI/discussion

Comment: Hi Dan , thnks for above discussion link . I have created a fiddle for the same [ Vertical Dygraph] (http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/udYqe/) {external .csv file is uploaded in external resources). The issues  i m facing is that second Y axis (y2) is not coming up just above the graph and also the Y2 label text is coming over label values (NeutronPorosity axis).I tried changing top-left of lable axis thru developers tool , but not able to adjust that .

Comment: does that latest dygraph library 1.0.1 supports touuch events . Previous one (1.2) was supporting it . DO I need to override touch events so that dese events work if graph is vertical